# .gitignore NuGet packages folder at any level but include .targets file at any level

Tags: windows, git, nuget, gitignore

I'm trying to implement the workaround for the [NuGet Package Restore Issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/12/nuget-package-restore-issues.aspx).

This involves ignoring the contents of all packages folders, at any level in the hierarchy. However, .targets files (typically in subfolders of packages folders) should not be ignored.

For example:

```
.gitignore
YourProject/
  YourProject.csproj
  packages/
    repositories.config
    Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.7/
      lib/
        foo.dll
      tools/
        Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets
```

Should include only files:

- .gitignore
- YourProject.csproj
- Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets

Windows, git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1.

I have read several answers on StackOverflow, checked the man page, and tried numerous variants without success.

This does not work:

```
packages/*
!*.targets
```

Nor this:

```
packages/*
!packages/**/*.targets
```

Nor this:

```
**/packages/*
!**/packages/**/*.targets
```

**Update:**

- This needs to work regardless of where the packages folder is at in the hierarchy.
- It needs to ignore files under packages, subfolders, sub-subfolders, etc.
- Other .gitignore lines, like `bin/`, must continue to work.

Comment: I think you can use `!*.targets   \n   /packages/*.*` (where \n is a newline), however this will not ignore extensionless files. The problem is `*` matches on directories, too.

Comment: @vcsjones Just tried it; that doesn't work either. It adds all the dlls under packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no 'good' way to do it (see [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) as a proof), however there is a hack around it.

Main issue with ignoring `packages/` of the bat is that git does not even check it's subdirectories due to directory being ignored.

Solution here - you will have to have 2 gitignore files. One regular, and one inside the packages directory that looks like this:

```
# ignore all files
*
# do not ignore directories
!*/
# do not ignore targets
!*.targets
# do not ignore gitignore
!*.gitignore
```

New example:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo/
$ mkdir foo
$ mkdir foo/bar
$ mkdir foo/bar/baz
$ touch foo/.foo
$ touch foo/bar/.foo
$ touch foo/bar/baz/.foo
$ touch regular.txt
$ touch foo/ignored.txt
$ touch foo/bar/baz/ignored-2.txt
$ cat foo/.gitignore
*
!*/
!*.foo
!regular.txt
!.gitignore
$ git add . && git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   foo/.foo
#       new file:   foo/bar/.foo
#       new file:   foo/bar/baz/.foo
#       new file:   regular.txt
#
```

Comment: Thank you! For your example you may want to include an undesired file under baz to show that it's not being added. Also, since I don't want to specify every project folder, it appears I can replace YourProject with `**`. Finally, it should be targets, not target. (Not for my sake but for future readers.)

Comment: On further testing this does not work (at least under Windows). To demonstrate, create the file `unwanted.txt` under `baz\fez`. That file will be added.

Comment: This is close: `**/baz/*  \n  **/baz/**/*  \n  !*/  \n  !*.foo`. There's at least one remaining issue: not ignoring directories affects other .gitignore lines, like `bin/`.

Comment: Wow - my last comment **still** isn't sufficient. You apparently have to do `**/packages/**/**/*`, `**/packages/**/**/**/*`, etc. Please tell me there's a better way.

Comment: And the `**/baz` bit only works if the folder is one level deep in the hierarchy. Move it to `Master/Project/baz` and it fails.

Comment: @TrueWill Good point. Re-wrote the answer from scratch, in new example everything in `foo/` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks again. That works, although I added `!.gitignore` to the packages file so that it would include itself. I wish there were a better way; this means our developers will have to remember to add this file to every project (not just every repository).

Answer (score 2):

The precedence of ignored paths is important, I take it.

I fixed this problem by specifying first what to keep then to ignore the rest of packages's content.

In  `.gitignore` file make sure you should have:

```
!packages/repositories.config
packages/
```

See https://github.com/danyandresh/Research/commit/65291219a1c1fbcdb2216c686767e8c46451baa1

Please note my `.gitignore` file is a simple copy of [Visual studio ignore list as found on github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)